# i have bootstrap Sidebar menu in my admin panel, when i click and fetch a link then two items are active , like in picture, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap Sidebar menu in my admin panel, when I click and fetch a link then two items are active, like in the picture, why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Check the li tag to see if the tag contains **active** option in distributor's package page. You need active on current page only & not on distrubutor's page when you are on dp page

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to that answer,

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Keeping a list item 'active' would mean, that item would be always selected. Check the list item class for this.

Comment: @x-babun I'm not sure whether this is what you were expecting. If it doesn't work, do update the question with your code, for us to help you further.